# CSS selector for image without source

Tags: css, selector

I know it is strange, but how can I select all the IMGs in a document which don't have a source (I am talking about the CSS selector)

That is, I want to select

```
<IMG>
```

but not

```
<IMG src="/my_file.png">
```

The answer is

```
img:not([src]) {
   /* style here */
}
```

Comment: Some other fun things with attributes - http://jsfiddle.net/kgveaye4/

Comment: @Paulie_D you could include the answer to the actual question in your fiddle, that would be even more helpful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `:not` selector

```
img:not([src]) {
   /* style here */
}
```